# I want to hide the packages included in drop down list without touching my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a drop-down list which has to choose the packages. But currently, I want to hide some packages for now without touching my product model.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
          <%= p.select :product_id, options_for_select( Listing::Product::PACKAGES.map { |k,v| [ v[:name], v[:rank] ] }, selected: p.object.product_id), {include_blank: true}, class: "form-control" %>
          <small>
            <%= p.label I18n.t('admin.listings.edit.configuration.select_product') %>
          </small>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `PACKAGES` constant kindly remove the not required items. Then write a separate method call from `before_filter`. Inside that method add your additional items to the PACKAGES based on your condition(s).

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily skip a few elements from packages collection, you can do this:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def ignored_package_keys
  %i[foo bar baz]
end

def packages_collection
  Listing::Product::PACKAGES.dup.
    delete_if { |k, _| ignored_package_keys.include? k }.
    map { |_, v| [ v[:name], v[:rank] ] }
end
```

and in views:

```
<%= p.select :product_id, options_for_select(packages_collection, selected: p.object.product_id), { include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control' %>
```